# Checking if an image is loaded, cross browser

Tags: javascript, image

I need a cross browser solution to find if an image is done loading.

I know about this:

```
var theImage = new Image()
theImage.src = 'http://pieisgood.org/images/slice.jpg' //yum, pie :)
//later...
if (theImage.complete) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Is that cross browser compatible (by that I mean FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE8+)? If not, how can I do this in a cross browser and jQuery-less way?

Comment: what is this `theImage.complete`? sure you didnt mean `onload`?

Comment: @VeXii https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement#DOM_properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something as:

```
var theImage = new Image()
theImage.src = 'http://pieisgood.org/images/slice.jpg' //yum, pie :)
theImage.isLoaded = false;
//later...
theImage.onload = function(){
    theImage.isLoaded = true;
    //do stuff
}
if(theImage.isLoaded){
    alert("Loaded");
}
document.body.appendChild(theImage); // VERY needed
```

Should work.

Just as it set attributes as the image is really loaded. :)

Comment: this does not check if the image is loaded. it only calls something once the image loads.

Comment: @Doorknob But this is really crossbrowser. If you want to check if the image is loaded, just set the function and set a attribute in it image, such in the new example.

Comment: True, but when it calls that something you'll know the image is loaded.

Comment: wait, what if the image is cached and it is already loaded by the time you call `onload`?

Comment: @Doorknob In theory the event is just called.. (as "load from cache" is the same as "load")

Comment: What I mean, is that what if by the time you call `onload`, the image has already loaded?

Comment: If you set the `onload` **before** setting the `src`, cached images will trigger the event properly

Comment: Does not work on iOS Safari

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the 'onload' event.

```
image.onload = function() {
};
```

This should be bound though, before you set the 'src' of the image.

Answer (score 1):

or just control it via html and call your function on specified img onload event

```
<img src="whatever.png" onload="dostuff()" />
```